# How to implement deserialization rules with RestSharp?

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I am trying to write wrapper for Capsule CRM API using RestSharp.

I have problem with their API service. It returns JSON object when data is present and empty string when object is absent on CRM.

e.g., look on contacts:

```
{"organisation":{"id":"97377548","contacts":"","pictureURL":"","createdOn":"2016-02-08T14:27:12Z","updatedOn":"2016-02-08T14:27:12Z","lastContactedOn":"2013-12-03T21:00:00Z","name":"some name"}}

{"organisation":{"id":"97377548","contacts":{"email":{"id":"188218414","emailAddress":"someemail"},"phone":{"id":"188218415","type":"Direct","phoneNumber":"phone"}},"pictureURL":"","createdOn":"2016-02-08T14:27:12Z","updatedOn":"2016-02-08T14:27:12Z","lastContactedOn":"2013-12-03T21:00:00Z","name":"some name"}}
```

To match contacts I have class:

```
public class Contacts
{
    public List<Address> Address { get; set; }
    public List<Phone> Phone { get; set; }
    public List<Website> Website { get; set; }
    public List<Email> Email { get; set; }
}
```

and property Contacts in class that I am trying to match:

```
public Contacts Contacts { get; set; }
```

Everything works fine when API returns JSON object, but I get exception when I get empty string for contacts from API:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.

How to avoid this problem?
Is there any way to make conditional matching based on data that is returned from API?
How I can tell RestSharp do not throw exception, just skip property if it can't match?

Comment: I don't see where the dictionary is in your classes?

Comment: I guess that RestSharp use IDictionary internally for property-value matcing: Contacts is IDictionary with keys "Address", "Phone", "Website".

Comment: as temporary solution I remove "contacts":"" from response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have control over your API, instead of returning `"contacts":""` in the response, return `"contacts":"{}"` and that should avoid your error.

---

If you cannot alter the response from the API, you'll need to implement a custom serializer, as "" to object isn't supported by RestSharp.

[This article](http://bytefish.de/blog/restsharp_custom_json_serializer/) summarizes how to use [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) as the serializer, which would enable you to use whatever rules you needed to for your deserialization.

**Article summary**

First, implement [ISerializer](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Serializers/ISerializer.cs) and [IDeserializer](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Deserializers/IDeserializer.cs) interfaces in a `NewtonsoftJsonSerializer` class. This would give you full control on how the JSON is desierialized, so you can make "" work for an empty object.

Then, to use it on a request:

```
 private void SetJsonContent(RestRequest request, object obj)
 {
     request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
     request.JsonSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
     request.AddJsonBody(obj);
 }
```

and to use it on a response:

```
private RestClient CreateClient(string baseUrl)
{
    var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);

    // Override with Newtonsoft JSON Handler
    client.AddHandler("application/json", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
    client.AddHandler("text/json", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
    client.AddHandler("text/x-json", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
    client.AddHandler("text/javascript", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
    client.AddHandler("*+json", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());

    return client;
}
```

Comment: It is not my API, it is public API of Capsule CRM, I can't change response. :-(

Comment: Ah ok, I was just assuming because of your temporary solution in the comments